Is there a way to change default DATE format in SQL Developer import wizard?
I am importing data from Excel file to Oracle table in SQL Developer. Default format for DATE fields is "Day, Month, RRRR". The format in the file is "DD-MON-YY HH24:MI", which is not in the dropdown menu, but import wizard accepts it if I paste it into Format field.
Is there a way to make "DD-MON-YY HH24:MI" default, instead of pasting it in for every DATE column?
When I paste "DD-MON-YY HH24:MI" into Format field, it works. But I would prefer not to do it over and over.

That looks like a bug, our parser is supposed to attempt to read the date information and auto-pick the best format available.
Workarounds:
1 - if you're doing the same types of imports, over and over again - use this feature 'Save/Restore' state. At the end of the wizard you can just save your work. Then when you go to import data to the same table again, start with 'Restore State' at the end.
2 - use SQLcl, you can codify this, all from the command line
 set load date_format DD-MON-YY HH24:MI

Then when you use the load command, it'll default to the setting.
